# tengo una serie de errores que salen cuando llamo a ostream para generar una sobrecarga de función

Tags: c++

estoy leyendo un libro 'aprenda c++ avanzado como si estuviera en primero' y en el tiene una clase numeros complejos, pero al tratar de compilar me salen varios errores
pondré solo la parte de los errores
complejo.h

```
   #pragma once
#ifndef __COMPLEJO_H__
#define __COMPLEJO_H__
#include <iostream>
class complejo
{
private:
    double real, imag;
public:
    //constructores
    complejo(void);
    complejo(double, double im = 0.0);
    complejo(const complejo&);
    //setThing
    void SetData(void);
    void SetReal(double);
    void SetImag(double);
    //GetThing
    double GetReal(void) { return real; }
    double GetImag(void) { return imag; }
    //sobrecarga operadores aritmeticos
    complejo operator+ (const complejo&);
    complejo operator- (const complejo&);
    complejo operator* (const complejo&);
    complejo operator/ (const complejo&);
    //sobrecarga operadores de asignacion
    complejo& operator = (const complejo&);
    //sobrecarga operador de comparacion
    friend int operator== (const complejo&, const complejo&);
    friend int operator!= (const complejo&, const complejo&);
    //sobrecarga del operador de insercion en el flujo de salida
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& , const complejo&);
     
};

#endif // !__COMPLEJO_H__
```

y complejo.cpp

```
#include"complejo.h"

//constructor por defecto 
complejo::complejo(void)
{
    real = 0.0;
    imag = 0.0;
}
//constructor general
complejo::complejo(double re, double im)
{
    real = re, imag = im;
}
//constructor de copia
complejo::complejo(const complejo& c)
{
    real = c.real;
    imag = c.imag;
}

//funcion mienbro setdata
void complejo::SetData(void)
{
    std::cout << "introduzca el valor rela del complejo :";
    std::cin >> real;
    std::cout << "introduzca el imaginario del complejo :";
    std::cin >> imag;

}
void complejo::SetReal(double re)
{
    real = re;
}

void complejo::SetImag(double im)
{
    imag = im;
}
//operador mienbro + sobrecargado
complejo complejo::operator+(const complejo& a)
{
    complejo suma;
    suma.real = real + a.real;
    suma.imag = imag + a.imag;
    return suma;
}

complejo complejo::operator-(const complejo& a)
{
    complejo resta;
    resta.real = real + a.real;
    resta.imag = imag + a.imag;
    return resta;
}

complejo complejo::operator*(const complejo& a)
{
    complejo mult;
    mult.real = real + a.real;
    mult.imag = imag + a.imag;
    return mult;
}

complejo complejo::operator/(const complejo& a)
{
    complejo div;
    div.real = real + a.real;
    div.imag = imag + a.imag;
    return div;
}

//operador mienbro de asignacion sobrecargado
complejo& complejo::operator=(const complejo& a)
{
    real = a.real;
    imag = a.imag;
    return (*this);
}
int operator== (const complejo& a, const complejo& b)
{
    if (a.real==b.real && a.imag==b.imag)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
int operator!= (const complejo& a, const complejo& b)
{
    if (a.real == b.real || a.imag == b.imag)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& co, const complejo& a)
{
    co << a.real;
    long fl = co.setf(ios::showpos);
    co << a.imag << "i";
    co.flags(fl);
    return co;
}
```

el main.cpp es

```
#include"complejo.h"


void main(void)
{
    complejo c1 = (1.0, 1.0);
    complejo c2 = (2.0, 2.0);
    complejo c3;
    c3.SetReal(5.0);
    c3.SetImag(2.0);
    complejo c4(4.0);
    complejo suma = c1 + c2;
    complejo resta = c1 - c2;
    complejo producto = c1 * c2;
    complejo cociente = c1 / c2;
    cout << c1 << "," << c2 << "," << c3 << "," << c4 << endl;
    cout << "primer complejo " << c1 << endl;
    cout << "segundo complejo " << c2 << endl;
    cout << "suma " << suma << endl;
    cout << "resta  " << resta << endl;
    cout << "producto " << producto << endl;
    cout << "cociente " << cociente << endl;

    if (c1==c2)
    {
        cout << "son iguales" << endl;

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "son distintos " << endl;
    }
    if (c1!=c2)
    {
        cout << "son distintos" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "son iguales " << endl;
    }

}
```

los errores son los siguientes

> Gravedad   Código   Descripción   Proyecto   Archivo   Línea   Estado
> suprimido Error   C2143   error de sintaxis: falta ';' delante de '&'
> complejo   C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.h
> 32    Error   C2433   'ostream': 'friend' no se permite en las
> declaraciones de datos   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.h   32
> Error   C4430   falta el especificador de tipo; se presupone int.
> Nota: C++ no admite default-int   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.h   32
> Error   C2238   símbolos (token) inesperados delante de ';'   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.h   32
> Error   C2872   'ostream': símbolo ambiguo   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.cpp   107
> Error   C2143   error de sintaxis: falta ';' delante de '&'   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.cpp   107
> Error   C4430   falta el especificador de tipo; se presupone int.
> Nota: C++ no admite default-int   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.cpp   107
> Error   C2086   'int ostream': nueva definición   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.cpp   107
> Error   C2872   'ostream': símbolo ambiguo   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.cpp   107
> Error   C2473   'operator <<': parece una definición de función, pero
> no hay ninguna lista de parámetros.   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.cpp   107
> Error   C4430   falta el especificador de tipo; se presupone int.
> Nota: C++ no admite default-int   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.cpp   107
> Error   C2065   'co': identificador no declarado   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.cpp   107
> Error   C2059   error de sintaxis: 'const'   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.cpp   107
> Error   C2143   error de sintaxis: falta ';' delante de '{'   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.cpp   108
> Error   C2447   '{': falta el encabezado de función (¿lista formal de
> estilo anterior?)   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.cpp   108
> Error   C2143   error de sintaxis: falta ';' delante de '&'   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.h   32
> Error   C2433   'ostream': 'friend' no se permite en las declaraciones
> de datos   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.h   32
> Error   C4430   falta el especificador de tipo; se presupone int.
> Nota: C++ no admite default-int   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.h   32
> Error   C2238   símbolos (token) inesperados delante de ';'   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\complejo.h   32
> Error   C2679   '<<' binario: no se encontró un operador que adopte un
> operando en la parte derecha de tipo 'complejo' (o bien no existe una
> conversión aceptable)   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\main.cpp   18    Error
> C2679   '<<' binario: no se encontró un operador que adopte un
> operando en la parte derecha de tipo 'complejo' (o bien no existe una
> conversión aceptable)   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\main.cpp   19    Error
> C2679   '<<' binario: no se encontró un operador que adopte un
> operando en la parte derecha de tipo 'complejo' (o bien no existe una
> conversión aceptable)   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\main.cpp   20    Error
> C2679   '<<' binario: no se encontró un operador que adopte un
> operando en la parte derecha de tipo 'complejo' (o bien no existe una
> conversión aceptable)   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\main.cpp   21    Error
> C2679   '<<' binario: no se encontró un operador que adopte un
> operando en la parte derecha de tipo 'complejo' (o bien no existe una
> conversión aceptable)   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\main.cpp   22    Error
> C2679   '<<' binario: no se encontró un operador que adopte un
> operando en la parte derecha de tipo 'complejo' (o bien no existe una
> conversión aceptable)   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\main.cpp   23    Error
> C2679   '<<' binario: no se encontró un operador que adopte un
> operando en la parte derecha de tipo 'complejo' (o bien no existe una
> conversión aceptable)   complejo
> C:\Users\Usuario\source\repos\complejo\complejo\main.cpp   24

Comment: Por favor comparte todo el archivo `complejo.h` y `complejo.cpp`. Si quieres también el `main.cpp`  aunque los errores relacionados con `complejo` deberían desaparecer cuando arregles lo otro.

Comment: muy bien lo comparto

Answer (score 0):

Hay 3 problemas principales en el código.

- El tipo de retorno de la función `main` debe ser `int`, no `void`.
- Tanto en `complejo.h` como en `complejo.cpp` no se reconoce el tipo `ostream` ya que está en el namespace `std`. Hay dos opciones para resolver esto:

  - Agregar `std::` antes de cualquier símbolo definido en el namespace. Por ejemplo `std::ostream`.
  - Escribir `using namespace std;` antes de hacer referencia a cualquier tipo dentro del namespace.
- En la función `operator<<`, el tipo que devuelve la función `co.setf` no es `long`. Necesitas hacer una conversión explícita. O si no sabes el tipo correcto, puedes dejar que el compilador lo infiera con [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto):

  ```
  auto variable = ...;
  ```